# CSS Animation has a bug in Safari, but working in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, css-animations

I've been trying to make a header animation that plays on page load. It works great in Firefox and Chrome, but in Safari there's a small bug with the transform.

First, the following image shows the webpage load in Chrome. It looks exactly the same on Firefox.
[Webpage load on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Orn46.gif)

Next, the following image shows the webpage load in Safari. Note the skip at the end as it hops down to where it should be all along.
[Webpage load on Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5p82.gif)

Selected code:

```css
.splash-site-header-1 { 
 display: block;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
}

.splash-header-nav-2 {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 max-width: 900px;
 width: 65%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 top: 50vh;
}

.splash-branding-3 {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: 40%;
 height: 18em;
 /*background-image: url("Ipsum_Logo.svg");
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
    background-color: red;
 overflow: hidden; 
 float: left;
 
    animation-name: logo-slide;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    
    -moz-animation-name: logo-slide;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-duration: 6s;

    -webkit-animation-name: logo-slide;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
}

.about-test-home {
 position: relative;
 width: 55%;
 height: auto;
 float: right;
 top: 144px; /* Half height */
 transform: translateY(-50%); 
 
 animation-name: word-slide;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    
    -moz-animation-name: word-slide;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-duration: 6s;

    -webkit-animation-name: word-slide;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
}

 .ath-quote { 
  float:right;
 }


@-moz-keyframes logo-slide {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-25%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    10% {
     opacity: 0;
    }
    55% {
     -moz-transform: translateX(75%);
     opacity: 1;
    }
    90% {
     -moz-transform: translateX(75%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes logo-slide {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-25%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    10% {
     opacity: 0;
    }
    55% {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(75%);
     opacity: 1;
    }
    90% {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(75%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes logo-slide {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-25%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    10% {
     opacity: 0;
    }
    55% {
     transform: translateX(75%);
     opacity: 1;
    }
    90% {
     transform: translateX(75%);
    }
    100% {
       transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes word-slide {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    90% {
     -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
     opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes word-slide {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    90% {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
     opacity: 0;    
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes word-slide {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;        
    }
    90% {
     transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
     opacity: 0;   
    }    
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="splash-site-header-1">
  <div class="splash-header-nav-2">
   <div id="splash-branding-3" class="splash-branding-3"><!--Various Wordpress php-->            </div>
          
            <div class="about-test-home">
    <div class="ath-quote">
     <h4><b>Aenean</b> eu leo quam. <b>Pellentesque</b> ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Vestibulum Dapibus Consectetur Cras</h4>
    </div>
   </div>
          </div>
  </div>
```

If there's anything more you want to see that would be helpful, let me know. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it doesn't apply the transform correctly from `.about-test-home`

Adding this to the class seems to fix it.

```
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
```

And it's probably a good idea to review all of your transforms and make sure all the necessary venfor-prefixes are being used where required.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is off-topic, but I found that animations with `animation-delay: 0ms` and `animation-duration: 0ms` didn't work in Safari 12. They need to be positive.